# Count the excel rows using the folder path

Tags: powershell

I have one folder named **customer** , under that there are multiple folders based on each customer name and under each customer I have excel of sheets which contain information in row wise.

I would like to extract this file structure into excel containing file path and number of rows contained in each of the excel.

I could able to list file names using below procedure.

> 1. Press **Win-E** to open Windows Explorer and locate the folder for which you need a file list.
> 2. Hold the **Shift** key, right-click the folder and select **Open Command Window Here.** This only works with folders, not libraries.
>      Libraries point to a specific folder, so select the folder located
>      under the library icon. If the library points to a drive, right-click
>      the drive letter from the folder tree.
> 3. Type `dir /b > dirlist.txt` without quotes and press **Enter**. This creates a list containing file names only. To include file sizes and
>      dates, type `dir > dirlist.txt` instead. To also include files in
>      sub-directories, type `dir /b /s > dirlist.txt` to create a list of
>      files with the full directory structure name, such as
>      **C:\folder\subdirectory\file.txt**.
> 4. Open Microsoft Excel and press **Ctrl-O** to bring up the Open dialog window.
> 5. Navigate into the folder containing the files. Click the file type drop-down menu and select **Text Files (*.prn,*.txt,*.cvs)**.
>      Double-click **dirlist.txt** to open it.
> 6. Click **Finish** in the Text Import Wizard window to use the default options and import the directory list into Excel.

Please help in counting the rows also.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any example code, or links you have already looked at?

Comment: Linux seems an inappropriate tool for processing excel files. AND StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing code. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambigous. I removed unnecessary/wrong tags.
Excel files can have more than one sheet, so you have to iterate/recurse the files from given startfolder and also all sheets in the workbook. Output is a table with the asked properties. Should be easy to save as a csv.

```
$BaseFolder = "X:\Path\to\Customers"
$xlCellTypeLastCell = 11 
$AllSheets = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[object]
$Excel = New-Object -com excel.application
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = "False"
$XLfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $BaseFolder -Filter *.xls* -File -Recurse
ForEach ($XLfile in $XLfiles) {
    $WorkBook = $Excel.workbooks.open($XLfile.FullName)
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $WorkBook.sheets.count; $i++){
        $Sheet = $WorkBook.Sheets.Item($i)
        $LastRow = $Sheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells($xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

        $Obj =  [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
            ExcelFPath= $XLfile.FullName
            Customer  = ($XLfile.Directory).Name
            ExcelFile = $XLfile.Name
            SheetNo   = $i
            RowCount  = $LastRow
        }
        $AllSheets.add($obj)
    }
    $Excel.Workbooks.Close()
}
$AllSheets | Format-Table -auto
## $AllSheets | Out-Gridview
```

Comment: Very nice. So *this* is the power of Powershell I have read so  much about. Thanks for sharing! Good luck to all.